# Django query to join data from two models without primary or foreign key

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm learning Django, so far so good, however I am stuck with the `get_query(self)` function.

I have two models in django no foreign in tables:

```
class Airport(models.Model):
   ID = models.AutoField()
   Name = models.CharField()
   City = models.CharField()
   ICAO = models.CharField()

class Airport_Frequency(models.Model):
   ICAO = models.CharField())
   ATC_Type = models.CharField()
   Frequency_MHz = models.DecimalField()
```

Now I want to create a listview but I want to join table fields `Airport.name` and `Airport_Frequency.ICAO` to show in frequency list - SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ICAO, b.ICAO, b.Name FROM airport as b, airport_frequency as a WHERE a.ICAO = b.ICAO
```

View:

```
class Airport_FrequencyListView(ListView):
    model = Airport_Frequency
```

How to refer in the `Airport_FrequencyListViewview` above to another model?

Comment: You should use a `ForeignKey`/`OneToOneField` to link the two together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django can not use joins which are not a part of the model. A good primary key in your case can be [ICAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICAO_airport_code) (a unique four letter identifier of an airport - worldwide unique). Large airports need more types of channels with different frequencies, therefore it is a one-to-many relationship.

```py
class Airport(models.Model):
   ICAO = models.CharField(max_length=4, primary_key=True)
   Name = models.CharField(...)
   City = models.CharField(...)

class Airport_Frequency(models.Model):
   airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport)  # Airport_id is the ICAO of the airport
   ATC_Type = models.CharField(...)
   Frequency_MHz = models.DecimalField(...)
```

views.py

```py
class Airport_FrequencyListView(ListView):
    queryset = Airport_Frequency.objects.select_related('airport')
    ...
```

template

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    {{ item.airport.ICAO }},{{ item.airport.Name }},{{ item.Frequency_MHz }}<br>
{% end for %}
```

Comment: Thanks , i used a selelect_related

Answer (score 0):

```
class Airport(models.Model):
   ID = models.AutoField()
   Name = models.CharField()
   City = models.CharField()
   ICAO = models.CharField()

class Airport_Frequency(models.Model):
   airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport, null=True)
   ICAO = models.CharField())
   ATC_Type = models.CharField()
   Frequency_MHz = models.DecimalField()
```

Then to access to the access to each other:

```
airport.airport_frequency
airport_frequency.airport
```